# Unable to receive webhooks with Sandbox Paypal

Tags: events, paypal, sandbox, webhooks

I'm trying to get notified via webhooks when a simple payment is made, however I don't receive any request from paypal on the specified URL. Here is what I've done:

I have 2 sandbox accounts: Facilitator and Buyer
Create an app (sanbox mode)
Add a webhook URL in that app

Now I go on woocommerce site where i configured my app with Paypal.
and when I make a payment to buy an item with a buyer account.

In developer dashboard the payment is received if I go to Sandbox -> Notifications: "Notification of Payment Received from test buyer", but the webhook page on my server is not called.
Also if I go to Developer Account -> Webhook Notifications and select the app I have this message: You don't have any events for the selected application

I believe my transactions are not being done correctly.
Can someone please help me with this.?

Comment: What is the payment type that you've done? Remembered that only REST API transaction supported for webhooks.

Comment: Thanks Ray for your response..!
Can we have a way to get web-hooks or notifications of transactions which are made through any way like Rest api transaction or with any other method.?

Comment: if you are referring to NVP API, Instant Payment Notifications might be an option. It works similar just like webhook.